# Flexbox - columns and ordering IOS

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, compass

I have build a Layout relying on Flexbox. On smaller screens the direction switches from "normal" to columns plus some change in ordering.

That does work in Chrome, FF. On Safari `@include flex-direction(column)` is creating a big mess and whole layout is thrown apart, therefor I have created a mixin like this:

```
@mixin flex-columns() {
  @include flex-direction(column);
  display: -webkit-box;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

That fixes the problems with IOS and looks as it should, except that `@inlcude order(<n>);` does not work any longer, neither on Chrome, nor on IOS, Firefox just works.

Far sake of simplicity here is a shortened version of the code:

```
<!-- html -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="child child-1">...</div>
    <div class="child child-2">...</div>
    <div class="child child-3">...</div>
</div>

//Sass (compass)
div.container {
    @include display-flex();

    div.child-1 {
        @inlcude flex(0 1 10%);
    }
    .
    .
    .
}

@media ... {
    div.container {
        @include flex-columns();

        div.child-1 { @include order(2) }
        div.child-2 { @include order(3) }
        div.child-3 { @include order(1) }

    }
}
```

Any Idea? If Safari does not support ordering if direction is set to columns, how could I exclude chrome from the safari fix (`display: -webkit-box;`)??

Thanks for help!

Comment: Check the spelling: `@inlcude flex(0 1 10%);` and `@inlcude flex-columns();`

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks! That's my favorite... Corrected It! But it's not the cause for the problem...

Comment: Maybe you could post the full code, so we could reproduce the problem. Or even a demo would be helpful (e.g., jsfiddle.net), preferably with compiled code, as not everybody uses preprocessors.